# How to make the argument to filter() a variable?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filter, google-cloud-datastore

I have this model

```
class Item(db.Model):
    ...   
    glam = db.StringProperty()
    casual = db.StringProperty()
    speaking = db.StringProperty()
```

and this handler with a form with radio buttons:

```
class SortForm(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""
            <form name="submit_form" action="/sortformhandler" method="post">
            Category: <input type="radio" name="image" value="image"> Image <br />
            Sorty by tag: <br />
            <input type="radio" name="tag" value="glam" /> Glam <br />
            <input type="radio" name="tag" value="formal" /> Formal <br />
            <input type="radio" name="tag" value="speaking" /> Speaking <br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
            """)
```

and this handler

```
class SortFormHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):

        query = Item.all()

        query.filter("glam =", "glam")
                for item in query:
            self.response.out.write("""<a href="%s"><image src="%s" height="110">%s</a>""" % 
                                       (item.url, item.image_source_url, item.title)  )
```

I've been trying to have something like

```
        query.filter("[self.request.get("tag")] =", [self.request.get("tag")])
```

so that when `glam` is chosen in the radio button I should have

```
        query.filter("glam =", "glam")
```

But I could not make this work. In other words, I am trying to make the argument to `filter()` a variable. Any suggestions?

I am trying to create tagging for the image library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query.filter(self.request.get("tag"), self.request.get("tag"))
```

The `=` is actually not required.

However, I'd also consider using a single StringProperty for the tag, since it appears that your 3 string properties are essentially booleans, and only one of them can be true at a time.

Comment: thanks, this works. But if there are 2 different items, 1 tagged `glam` the other tagged `speaking`; filtering twice for each will not return those 2 items; because the filter will be looking for 1 item tagged `glam` and `speaking`. This seems to be a different question so I will ask separately. Thanks again.

Comment: "...consider using a single `StringProperty` for the tag, since it appears that your 3 string properties are essentially booleans, and only one of them can be true at a time." Not sure I understand this. Do you mean, in the `Item` model use `tag` as a `StringProperty` and enter "glam", "speaking" etc in that column? If so, yes, I should try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Would that do what you're looking for:

```
choice = self.request.get("tag")
query.filter(choice, choice)
```

However, I agree with Wooble below. The way you have designed it, you dont' really use `glam`, `casual`, `speaking` as `StringProperty`, since they are either empty or have a specific value.

What you probably want to do is have a `tag` property that can take different values from *glam*, *formal*, *speaking*, ...

```
class Item(db.Model):
    ...   
    tag = db.StringProperty()
```

And then you would query your db like so:

```
query.filter("tag", self.request.get("tag"))
```