# How to filter() for different items?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filter, google-cloud-datastore

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829138/how-to-make-the-argument-to-filter-a-variable).

I am using the same model

```
class Item(db.Model):
    ...   
    glam = db.StringProperty()
    casual = db.StringProperty()
    speaking = db.StringProperty()
```

and assume that I have 2 items and 1 is tagged "glam" the other tagged "speaking".

If I filter like this

```
    query.filter("glam", "glam")
    query.filter("speaking"), "speaking")
```

the filter returns none because this looks for 1 item tagged "glam" and "speaking".

How do I filter for separate items?

**Update**

`Item` table may look like this:

```
         glam    speaking
        -------------------
item1
item2    glam
item3            speaking
item4
item5    glam
```

I'd like to filter "glam" and "speaking"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current schema and the current datastore API, you cannot acheive this with a single query.

If 'glam', 'casual', and 'speaking' are mutually exclusive, you can use an `IN` query on a single field:

```
class Item(db.Model):
   ...
   tag = db.StringProperty()

query.filter("tag IN", ["glam", "speaking"])
```

You could also use the experimental [Datastore Plus API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/) and make an OR query (which is implemented by merging the results of two queries internally):

```
# Note: Your model must be a Datastore Plus model; this may require some restructuring!
q1 = query.filter("glam =", "glam")
q2 = query.filter("speaking =", "speaking")
for result in q1.OR(q2):
    ....
```

Note that the datastore plus API is still in development, so I'm not sure if these queries are run in parallel *yet*, but they should be eventually. Additionally, since the Datastore Plus API is still experimental and under development, you may have to change your code in response to API flux. You do get to control when these updates occur though, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to use the experimental Datastore Plus API at this point. Then, what is the best way to handle `image tagging` in datastore? Should I change my schema and use `one-to-many` relations?

Comment: You can use a StringListProperty (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling.html#Lists) - you can then do an AND query by simply using multiple equality filters on the same property.

Comment: I tried the StringListProperty but I noticed that if I use multiple filters for "glam" and "casual"; an item with tags ["glam", "casual"] will be returned but another item with tag [glam] will not be returned.

Comment: list solution appeared to be the best for now and I switched to that. It works great. Thanks again.